# I can`t edit data submitted to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have this line in views/lendings/_form.html.erb:

`<%= simple_form_for(@lending, url: save_order_tippings_path, method: :post) do |f| %>`

It sends data to an action called  "save_order" in tippings controller.

It`s working fine... but, if I try to edit the data and click on submit, it saves another record in database instead of update the one that I want to edit.

I want to send data to lendings controller/update action when I try to edit it, but i cant to data because data is being submitted to tippings controller.

Any idea? (excuse my english)

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you created save_order in tippings controller instead of having `new` and `create` actions in lendings controller?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there's any specific reason why you have different route for creating the lending. But, this is how you can achieve what you've asked for:

```
if @lending.new_record?
  form_url = save_order_tippings_path
  method = :post
else
  form_url = lendings_path(@lending)
  method = :put
end

<%= simple_form_for(@lending, url: form_url, method: method) do |f| %>
```